# Functions and buttons JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

The program I am trying to write is a little more complicated but here is a simple addition and subtraction evaluation code to help understand what I am trying to do.

```js
let x0 = document.getElementsByClassName('x0').value;
let y0 = document.getElementsByClassName('y0').value;

function addTion(num1, num2) {
  return (num1 + num2);
}

function subTion(num1, num2) {
  return (num1 - num2);
}

function Evaluate() {
  if (x0 > y0) {
    console.log(addTion(x0, y0));
    console.log(x0);
  } else if (x0 < y0) {
    console.log(subTion(x0, y0));
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name='viewpoint' content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Interp-Xtrap</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form name="getData">
      <label for="x0">X0:</label>
      <input type="text" id="point" name="x0" size="10px">
      <label for="y0">Y0:</label>
      <input type="text" id="point" name="y0" size="10px">
      <button type="button" id="button" onclick=Evaluate()>Evaluate</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
```

When I input 1 and 2 for X0 and Y0 respectively, I expect to see -1 as result.
#What is the problem with my code?

Comment: What do you see instead of the expected result?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('x0')` has no `value` property. Also you have duplicate ids `point`. `id` must be unique at all times. Lastly, none of your elements uses the class names you want to select by. Maybe you were looking for `document.getElementsByName('x0')[0]`? One more thing, the `for` attribute on `label` needs to reference the `id` of an input element, not the `name`.

Comment: Nothing at all, the result console is empty

Comment: @HidayatRzayev Nothing shows on the result at all, I tried displaying even the values of x0 and y0 but it appears after I click on Evaluate, those values are not even fetched by the script

Comment: @connexo Interesting! In my original code, I use the IDs for styling and didn't want to have duplicate chunks of codes for each of my form fields. I have changed from getElementsByClassName to getElementsByName but still no result.

Comment: @Pozeidon check the answer below

Answer (score 2):

I would initiate the values with `null` values. As soon as you click the evaluate button, the values are retrieved via the `getElementById` method. With the if and else condition your methods are called.

```js
let x0 = null
let y0 = null

function addTion(num1, num2) {
  return (num1 + num2);
}

function subTion(num1, num2) {
  return (num1 - num2);
}

function evaluateVal() {
  x0 = document.getElementById('x0').value;
  y0 = document.getElementById('y0').value;

  if (x0 > y0) {
    console.log(addTion(x0, y0));
    console.log(x0);
  } else {
    console.log(subTion(x0, y0));
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name='viewpoint' content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Interp-Xtrap</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form name="getData">
      <label for="x0">X0:</label>
      <input type="text" id="x0" name="x0" size="10px">
      <label for="y0">Y0:</label>
      <input type="text" id="y0" name="y0" size="10px">
      <button type="button" id="button" onclick="evaluateVal()">Evaluate</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I just implemented your solution in my main program and it works perfectly. I have also tried to create classes to handle the style for the input fields but It doesn't work, what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Do you use `#point` in your .css-file? then you know where the error is and have to add a class to the input or use the custom id `#x0` & `#y0`.

Comment: Remember `x0`and  `y0` in your code are `strings`.